# Timestamp comparision not working properly for presto cassandra

Tags: mysql, cassandra, presto

I have the below presto query to retrieve data from cassandra

select * from table where created_time >= '2017-03-23 00:00:00.0' and created_time <= '2017-03-25 00:00:00.0';

The table has 70 rows with created_time as 2017-03-25 but the above query is not returning me all the rows.

created_time is defined as timeuuid in cassandra. Can someone help me why the query does not work

Comment: what is your table structure ?

Comment: Who in mysql related to here?

Comment: If you do `select * from table limit 10;`, what values do you get in create_time? Keep in mind that in Presto, the `timeuuid` type is mapped to `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

If `created_time` is defined as `timeuuid`, I would think that a query predicate  would compare that to a `timeuuid` value, not a string or a date string.

We can use the `minTimeuuid` and `maxTimeuuid` functions to generate values we can compare to a `timeuuid` column.

If we want rows with `created_time` sometime on March 25, we probably want the comparison to be "less than" the 26th '2017-03-26'

For example:

```
   where created_time >= minTimeuuid('2017-03-25 00:00+0000') 
     and created_time <  minTimeuuid('2017-03-26 00:00+0000')
```

Comment: I am writing the query in presto and i get the following error when i use the minTimeuuid function:
Query 20170403_224330_25606_q2qw7 failed: line 1:106: Function mintimeuuid not registered

Comment: Apparently, presto maps Cassandra `timeuuid` type to VARCHAR, and presto doesn't support the Cassandra  minTimeuuid function. Presto should invite extensions that better supports `timeuuid` and the `minTimeuuid` function. If extending presto isn't a desirable option, then you'd need to explore some other alternatives, such as adding a `timestamp` column, which presto does support. Or, implementing a function that mimics the Cassandra minTimeuuid function (returning an equivalent value), and using that value in the Cassandra query...  `created_time > 'mygenerateduuidvalue'`.